# How is System.DateTime.Year (and its other properties) implemented?

Tags: c#, c++, datetime

I am working on a C++ semi-port of the C# DateTime structure. (It's public domain if you care to [check it out](https://github.com/TheBuzzSaw/DateTimePlusPlus).) I really like having the class revolve around a single private 64-bit integer. It makes many of the operations super simple and keeps the class lightweight. The parts I'm struggling on are the calculations from ticks to the year, month, or day. Currently, [I use loops](https://github.com/TheBuzzSaw/DateTimePlusPlus/blob/master/DateTime.cpp#L92) to get the right answer: I subtract a year's worth of ticks at a time so that I can subtract a leap year's worth of ticks at the right time.

The good news is that it gets the right answer. I would simply prefer to use a direct mathematical approach if possible. I know C# isn't open source, but is there a way to see DateTime's implementation? If not, where can I find the math for converting N days to a year, month, and day?

Please, no comments on premature optimization. I'm not on a deadline. I just want to make this better. It's a learning experience.

UPDATE - To anyone curious, I also did manage to see the implementation in Mono. There is a plain text DateTime.cs in the source code.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Dates are a pit of unending developer sorrow and best left to other people, so it's easy to apportion blame when it all goes wrong!

Comment: Here's a taster of some of the awful mistruths you too might mistakenly believe. http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time... and yet more here... http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time-wisdom

Comment: @spender Hahaha indeed. Trust me, I do have limits. I don't plan on revolutionizing the DateTime API realm. Maybe I'm just addicted to small math puzzles.

Comment: Small math puzzles for the win! Just checking that you're not insane ;)

Comment: @spender That's a different discussion. My sanity is definitely in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are excerpts from a `Date` structure that I previously implemented. The constructor contains the main logic for converting a number of days since 1/1/0001 (the "serial number") to a year, month, and day. It's based on the actual source code for `System.DateTime`, but I've used more descriptive variable names and added comments.

When converting from a number of `DateTime` ticks, you'll want to divide by `TimeSpan.TicksPerDay` first to get the serial number.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a date between January 1, 0001 CE, and December 31, 9999 CE, in the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
/// </summary>
public struct Date
{
    public const Int32 DaysPerYear = 365;
    public const Int32 MonthsPerYear = 12;

    private const UInt32 MaxSerialNumber = 3652058;
    private const UInt32 December = 11; // 0-based
    private const UInt32 DaysInDecember = 31;

    private const UInt32 LeapYearInterval1 = 4;
    private const UInt32 LeapYearInterval2 = 100;
    private const UInt32 LeapYearInterval3 = 400;

    private const UInt32 DaysPerLeapYearInterval1 =
        DaysPerYear * LeapYearInterval1 + 1; // +1 leap day every 4 years
    private const UInt32 DaysPerLeapYearInterval2 =
        DaysPerLeapYearInterval1 * (LeapYearInterval2 / LeapYearInterval1) - 1; // -1 leap day every 100 years
    private const UInt32 DaysPerLeapYearInterval3 =
        DaysPerLeapYearInterval2 * (LeapYearInterval3 / LeapYearInterval2) + 1; // +1 leap day every 400 years

    private static readonly UInt32[] DaysOfYear =
        new UInt32[(MonthsPerYear + 1) * 2]
        {
            0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365,
            0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366,
        };

    private readonly UInt16 _zeroBasedYear; // 0 to 9998
    private readonly Byte _zeroBasedMonth; // 0 to 11
    private readonly Byte _zeroBasedDay; // 0 to 30

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Date" /> structure to a specified serial number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serialNumber">
    /// The <see cref="SerialNumber" /> of the new <see cref="Date" />.
    /// </param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
    /// <paramref name="serialNumber" /> is less than 0 or greater than 3652058.
    /// </exception>
    public Date(Int32 serialNumber)
    {
        Require.IsBetween("serialNumber", serialNumber, 0, (Int32)MaxSerialNumber);
        UInt32 days = (UInt32)serialNumber;

        // Find the first year of the 400-year period that contains the date:
        UInt32 zeroBasedYear = days / DaysPerLeapYearInterval3 * LeapYearInterval3;
        days %= DaysPerLeapYearInterval3;

        // Within the 400-year period, advance to the first year of the century that contains the date:
        UInt32 centuries = days / DaysPerLeapYearInterval2;
        zeroBasedYear += centuries * LeapYearInterval2;

        // Special case: If the date is the last day (December 31) of the 400-year period,
        // then "centuries" will be out of range because the fourth century has one more day than the others:
        if (centuries == LeapYearInterval3 / LeapYearInterval2)
            goto December31;

        days %= DaysPerLeapYearInterval2;

        // Within the century, advance to the first year of the 4-year period that contains the date:
        zeroBasedYear += days / DaysPerLeapYearInterval1 * LeapYearInterval1;
        days %= DaysPerLeapYearInterval1;

        // Within the 4-year period, advance to the year that contains the date:
        UInt32 years = days / DaysPerYear;
        zeroBasedYear += years;

        // Special case: If the date is the last day (December 31) of the 4-year period,
        // then "years" will be out of range because the fourth year has one more day than the others:
        if (years == LeapYearInterval1)
            goto December31;

        days %= DaysPerYear;

        // Estimate the month using an efficient divisor:
        Int32 index = GetDaysOfYearIndex(zeroBasedYear);
        UInt32 zeroBasedMonth = days / 32;

        // If the estimate was too low, adjust it:
        if (days >= DaysOfYear[index + (Int32)zeroBasedMonth + 1])
            ++zeroBasedMonth;

        _zeroBasedYear = (UInt16)zeroBasedYear;
        _zeroBasedMonth = (Byte)zeroBasedMonth;
        _zeroBasedDay = (Byte)(days - DaysOfYear[index + (Int32)zeroBasedMonth]);
        return;

    December31:
        _zeroBasedYear = (UInt16)(zeroBasedYear - 1);
        _zeroBasedMonth = (Byte)December;
        _zeroBasedDay = (Byte)(DaysInDecember - 1);
    }

    private static Int32 GetDaysOfYearIndex(UInt32 zeroBasedYear)
    {
        return !InternalIsLeapYear(zeroBasedYear) ? 0 : MonthsPerYear + 1;
    }

    private static Boolean InternalIsLeapYear(UInt32 zeroBasedYear)
    {
        UInt32 year = zeroBasedYear + 1;
        return
            (year % LeapYearInterval1 == 0) &&
            (year % LeapYearInterval2 != 0 || year % LeapYearInterval3 == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now we're talkin'. And yeah, I did figure out to convert my ticks to days before beginning the calculations. That's just as far as I got before I cowered in fear behind my loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily get at the .NET implementation (without decompiling) but you're welcome to look at the source to [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) - my date and time project for .NET based on [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net). That obviously has to do similar things.

Personally I *wouldn't* use `DateTime` as a starting point for a date and time API. It has [various unfortunate aspects](http://noda-time.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) to it. There are much better date/time APIs to look at (not just Noda Time, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Try using reflector to see the implementation? Although it may end up making calls to some unmanaged code. Or alternatively look at Mono to see if they have an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone discovering this question later, I found the *actual* source code to `DateTime`.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs